# Refreshing parent Kendo MVC Grid when Child grid updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to update the parent grid when the child grid record is updated, is that possible?  If so could anyone provide any advice on it?

Firstly I'm not sure which event would be best to use on the child grid. I want the child grid's CRUD action to fire, then load the contents of the parent again, preferably by Ajax.

Below is my grid as is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bills: Parent/Child";
}

<h2>Bills Index</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BillParent>()
    .Name("BillParentsGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(h => h.Category);
        columns.Bound(h => h.Description);
        columns.Bound(h => h.Amount);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
        }).Width(95);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(h => h.BillId);
            model.Field(h => h.BillId).Editable(false);
        })
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("BillParents_Read", "Bill"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("BillParent_Update", "Bill"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("BillChildren")

      )

<script id="BillChildren" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BillChild>()
          .Name("BillChildren_#=BillId#")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(d => d.BillId).Width(50);
              columns.Bound(d => d.Description).Width(150);
              columns.Bound(d => d.Amount).Width(80);
              columns.Command(command =>
              {
                  command.Edit();
                  command.Destroy();
              }).Width(55);
          })
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(d => d.BillId);
                  model.Field(d => d.BillId).Editable(false);
              })
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("BillChildren_Read", "Bill", new { id = "#=BillId#" }))
            .Update(update => update.Action("BillChild_Update", "Bill"))
            .Create(create => create.Action("BillChild_Create", "Bill", new { id = "#=BillId#" }))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("BillChild_Destroy", "Bill")))

          .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
          .ToClientTemplate()
          )
</script>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cracked it in the end.

The Event needs to be on the dataSource, using the Sync event, not on the grid itself.

**Short version**

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .Model(model =>
                  {
                      model.Id(d => d.BillId);
                      model.Field(d => d.BillId).Editable(false);
                  })
                  .Events(events =>
                  {
                      events.Error("error_handler");
                      events.Sync("resyncParentGrid");
                  })

    <script>
        function resyncParentGrid(e) {
            var parentData = $('#BillParentsGrid').data("kendoGrid");
            parentData.dataSource.read();
        }
    </script>
```

**Full Version**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BillParent>()
    .Name("BillParentsGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(h => h.Category).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(h => h.Description);
        columns.Bound(h => h.Amount).Width(80);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
        })
        .Title("Commands").Width(150);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(h => h.BillId);
            model.Field(h => h.BillId).Editable(false);
        })
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("BillParents_Read", "Bill"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("BillParent_Update", "Bill"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("BillChildren")

      )

<script id="BillChildren" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BillChild>()
          .Name("BillChildren_#=BillId#")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(d => d.BillId).Width(50);
              columns.Bound(d => d.Description).Width(150);
              columns.Bound(d => d.Amount).Width(80);
              columns.Command(command =>
              {
                  command.Edit();
                  command.Destroy();
              })
                  .Title("Commands").Width(150);
          })
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(d => d.BillId);
                  model.Field(d => d.BillId).Editable(false);
              })
              .Events(events =>
              {
                  events.Error("error_handler");
                  **events.Sync("resyncParentGrid");**
              })
              .Read(read => read.Action("BillChildren_Read", "Bill", new { id = "#=BillId#" }))
              .Update(update => update.Action("BillChild_Update", "Bill"))
              .Create(create => create.Action("BillChild_Create", "Bill", new { id = "#=BillId#" }))
              .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("BillChild_Destroy", "Bill"))
          )
          .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
          .ToClientTemplate()
          )
</script>



<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }

    function resyncParentGrid(e) {
        var parentData = $('#BillParentsGrid').data("kendoGrid");
        parentData.dataSource.read();
    }
</script>
```